# knitr xtable with long head note too long, stretch out the entire table

Tags: latex, knitr, xtable, rnw

I'm new to `knitr` and Latex stuff, so this may be a very naive question, but I failed to find a correct answer.

I'm doing empirical research that sometimes, we need to add headnotes as instruction for a complex table.

Below is the code I'm currently using (in a file named `test.Rnw`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
% packages intend to rotate table
\usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in, left = 0.5in, right = 0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
 \section{TEST CODE}
<<Table_Test Test Table, echo=FALSE, results="asis", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
set.seed(138744)
df_1 <- data.frame("id"  = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b','b'),
                   'time' = c(1991,1991,1991, 2001,2003,2004),
                   'value' = c('x', 'y','x','z','w','u'))

table_instruction <-"This is only here to test whether the text is too long. This is only here to test whether the text is too long"

print(xtable(df_1,# first zero "represents" row numbers which we skip later
             # align and put a vertical line (first "l" again represents column of row numbers)
             align = paste0("ll", paste0(rep("c", dim(df_1)[2]-1),  collapse = "")),
             caption = "Test Table",
             label='test-tab'),
      floating = TRUE,
      size="\\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\\selectfont", #Change size; useful for bigger tables "normalsize" "footnotesize"
      include.rownames = FALSE, #Don't print rownames
      include.colnames = TRUE, #We create them ourselves
      caption.placement = "top", #"top", NULL
      hline.after=NULL, #We don't need hline; we use booktabs
      # floating.environment = 'sidewaystable',# to rotate the table
      # whether \begin{Table} should be created (TRUE) or not (FALSE)
      sanitize.text.function = force, # Important to treat content of first column as latex function
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(-1, -1, 0, nrow(df_1)),
                        command = c(paste0("\\toprule \n"),# NEW row

                                    paste0("\\multicolumn{", dim(df_1)[2],"}{@{}l}{", table_instruction,"} \\\\" ,
                                           "\\cmidrule(l){1-", dim(df_1)[2], "}"),
                                    
                                    paste0("\\cmidrule(l){1-", dim(df_1)[2], "} \n"),
                                    
                                    paste0("\\bottomrule \n \\multicolumn{",dim(df_1)[2],"}{l}",
                                           "",paste("{\\scriptsize{", "***$p$< .001, **$p$< .01, *$p$< .05","}}",sep = " "),"\\\\"))

                        )
    )

@
\end{document}
```

Then I render the above code using the code below:

```
rm(list=ls())
library("knitr")
knit2pdf('test.Rnw')
```

It works successfully, the problem is that the headnotes (right above the header row) is not self-contained to the table's width. Instead, it stretches the table way too wide.

[image]

Any suggestion on how to make the long headnotes, no matter how long, to have consistent width with the table?